# Hadoop--Compile successfully but after submit job broke down

Tags: hadoop

I write my own Scheduler in `Hadoop2.6.0` inherit AbstractYarnScheduler.
I compile successfully but when submit job in hadoop, RM broke down.

Here is the log in Master Node

```
2015-07-19 13:31:59,931 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1437327062733_0001 State change from NEW to NEW_SAVING
**2015-07-19 13:31:59,932 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Error in dispatcher thread**
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnServerResourceManagerServiceProtos$ApplicationStateDataProtoOrBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Records.newRecord(Records.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.records.ApplicationStateData.newInstance(ApplicationStateData.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.records.ApplicationStateData.newInstance(ApplicationStateData.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$StoreAppTransition.transition(RMStateStore.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$StoreAppTransition.transition(RMStateStore.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$SingleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore.handleStoreEvent(RMStateStore.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$ForwardingEventHandler.handle(RMStateStore.java:839)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$ForwardingEventHandler.handle(RMStateStore.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServerResourceManagerServiceProtos$ApplicationStateDataProtoOrBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
2015-07-19 13:31:59,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Exiting, bbye..
2015-07-19 13:31:59,937 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2015-07-19 13:31:59,938 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8088
2015-07-19 13:31:59,938 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2015-07-19 13:31:59,938 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2015-07-19 13:31:59,944 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 8032, call org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB.getApplicationReport from 129.10.58.155:50992 Call#42 Retry#0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.utils.BuilderUtils.newApplicationResourceUsageReport(IILorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/Resource;Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/Resource;Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/Resource;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationResourceUsageReport;
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMServerUtils.<clinit>(RMServerUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl.createAndGetApplicationReport(RMAppImpl.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.getApplicationReport(ClientRMService.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.getApplicationReport(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
2015-07-19 13:32:00,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8032
2015-07-19 13:32:00,040 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8032
2015-07-19 13:32:00,040 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8033
2015-07-19 13:32:00,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8033
2015-07-19 13:32:00,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2015-07-19 13:32:00,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2015-07-19 13:32:00,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping ResourceManager metrics system...
2015-07-19 13:32:00,042 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2015-07-19 13:32:00,042 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system stopped.
2015-07-19 13:32:00,042 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-07-19 13:32:00,042 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, igonring any new events.
2015-07-19 13:32:01,042 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:02,043 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:03,043 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:04,043 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:05,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:06,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:07,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
2015-07-19 13:32:08,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Waiting for AsyncDispatcher to drain.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error information, the system can't find the class `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServerResourceManagerServiceProtos$ApplicationStateDataProtoOrBuilder`, do you add the class to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be some user session/permission issue, I got same error in my standalone instance (Ubuntu Desktop 16 LTE, jdk1.8.92 & Hadoop 2.7.2). It works normal again if I restart my machine & start over again. it keeps popping up same error if I just re-login, restart daemons, resubmit the job on the same terminal session.

Were you able to fix this issue?

Steps to reproduce on my machine are:

(1)Start terminal, login (on terminal) to hadoop dedicated user hduser (a sudo user) using command: su hduser

(2)start hadoop daemons using commands: start-dfs.sh & start-yarn.sh

(3)I can see all processes with jps command.

(4)Few MR jobs completed successfully. I submit same job after about 10-15 min.

(5)hduser user session is thrown out & land in regular desktop user session.